# A Concave and Scale invariant Function with two zeros that is not piecewise

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm looking for a one variable function that is scale invariant, has two zeros and concave and I want it to have a single formula so no piecewise function.

I can't think of anything. I would be very grateful if you can give me any hint whether such a function exists or not.

Something like this

[image]

a shifted quadratic function except that it should also be scale invariant.

**Edit:** what i mean by [Scale invariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_invariance).

$$f(kx)=k^{\alpha}f(x)$$

Comment: What do you mean by "scale invariant"?

Comment: here is the definition [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_invariance) $f(kx)=k^{\alpha}f(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)=0$ then $f(kx)=k^\alpha f(x)=0$ for all $k$.  So if $x\ne 0$ and $f(x)=0$, then $f$ is identically zero.  So if $f$ were scale-invariant and had two zeroes, one of them would be other than $x=0$, and then $f=0$, so it has lots more than two zeroes.

Comment: Thanks for the respond but I don't understand it. Can you elaborate a little more. Are you saying that such a function doesn't exit?

Comment: This makes me think of periodic functions, like $Cos(x)$ function, except that it is not scale invariant.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the only function satisfying your conditions is $f=0$.

Comment: I got it now. So for $x_1\neq0$ if $f(x_1)=0$ then for every $k$ we obtain $f(k x_1)=0$. And since there is no limit for $k$ this could be infinite number of zeros. Thanks again for your help.